# sweave caption on top of the figure

Tags: r, knitr, sweave

I would like to show a caption above a figure. I looked around for some solutions, but I still can not achieve my goal.
This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

<<fig1, echo = F, fig.width=7, fig.height=5, fig.cap= "This is a caption">>=
x = 1:50
y = x^2
plot(x, y)
@

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the LaTeX method of adding a caption, `knitr` won't do it automatically.  For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{This is a caption}
<<fig1, echo = F, fig.width=7, fig.height=5>>=
x = 1:50
y = x^2
plot(x, y)
@
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

If you skip the `fig.cap` option, you just get the figure inserted, not as a LaTeX floating figure, but you can still put it in your own float.  You may need to add an explicit `\label` if you want to reference the figure, because `knitr` won't add that for you in this simple mode.